# Determine if position in html string is within an anchor tag

Tags: php, html, regex, preg-match-all

I am currently using `preg_match_all()` to find all words that begin with a specific of preffix. For example, if the preffix is `cat`, then `catsup` would be considered a match whereas `housecat` would not.

Once these instances and their offsets are found, I am cycling through them and essentially encapsulating them with an anchor tag.

*(Question Continued Below Code)*

---

```
//Escape all non-standard characters
$preffix = sanitizePreffix($part['modlnoPreffix']);

//All Words Starting with preffix string
$pattern = "/".$preffix.'/'; 

//Find Matches
preg_match_all($pattern , $item['body'], $matches,PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
$matches = array_reverse($matches[0]);

if (count($matches)>0){
    foreach ($matches as $match){
        $text = $match[0];
        $offset = (int)$match[1];
        $endOffset = $offset + strlen($text);
        $url = "/specsheet_getPreffixParts.php?m=".urlencode($text);

        //Insert ending </a> Tag                    
        $item['body'] = str_insert('</a>', $item['body'], $endOffset);

        //Insert Starting <a ...> Tag
        $item['body'] = str_insert("<a rel='".$url."' href='javascript:void(0);'>", $item['body'], $offset);
    }
}
```

---

The one catch is that I need to check each resulting index to make sure that

1. The result is **not** already linked like `<a href='...'>catsup</a>`
2. The result is **not** within the starting `<a>` tag itself like `<a href='/part/catsup'> ... </a>`

I'm sure I could easily create a function that would step backwards one character at a time searching for `<a` and then step forward one character at a time looking for `</a>`, but this seems a bit silly to me.

**My question is:** Is there a better way to do this? My initial instinct is to make this part of the initial search pattern used by `preg_match_all` - in other words ....

How would I `find all words that start with 'cat' but are not located between a '<a' and a '</a>'`

Comment: FYI: It's spelled `prefix`, save you a keystroke ;-)

Comment: @Fred I noticed that as well. I am modifying someone elses (usually stellar) code. I'll do a Search + Replace later on. Thanks! :)

Comment: @STTLCU I actually came across that in my searches. I'm not really trying to "Parse HTML" - This is a basic text search that does not need to "Understand the complexities of HTML" - since I already do :) Plus, the HTML is super basic, since I am on control of it the entire time. Thanks for the info though.

Comment: yeah i understood, that's why I added the notice in brackets :) it's always make me laugh to read that answer, anyway :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I disagree that the recommendation to use a parser doesn't necessarily apply to this question.  I would say it certainly does, it look likely you are dealing with enough structural complexity to make the regex approach infeasible.

However, assuming you actually are dealing with a basic enough subset of HTML syntax to be parsed by a regex, then I notice that in the examples given, you could just look for `<\a>` to follow the matched string somewhere, and reject the match if it appears, which can be done with a simple enough lookahead, like:

```
$pattern = "/".$preffix.'(?!.*<\/a>)/';
```

or perhaps, to ensure the lookahead only looks at the very next tag seen,

```
$pattern = "/".$preffix.'(?![^<]*<\/a>)/';
```

Comment: I already thought of this approach - but it fails if I have two similar prefixes.. for example if my first prefix is `TTM` and my second prefix is `TT`, the Link that has `<a href='...'>TTM...</a>` will also be linked when `TT` comes around, since `TT</a>` is not found. Make sense? Keep in mind, the words BEGIN with the prefix, but may have several letters between the prefix and the `</a>`

Comment: Unless I misunderstand something, that is what the provided regex does.  It will look for the `<\a>` tag anywhere following the matched prefix (note the `.*` preceding `<\/a>` in the lookahead.

Comment: By the way, I assume that `$preffix`, by the time it's used looks something like `cat\w*+`?  Don't really know what `sanitizePreffix` is doing, but if it was working as described before, I'dd guess something like that.

Comment: This ended up being the solution that worked the best. `sanitizePreffix` just escapes the special chars in the string.

Comment: just one other thing... how would I got about this if I wanted to match the entire word - and not just words that start with `X`?

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean.  You want to match any word that is not within <a> tags in the ways mentioned above?  I guess you could replace the prefix with `\w++`.  Not sure that's what you are looking for at all though.

Comment: What I mean is: Rather finding a word that starts with "TT" - what if I wanted to find all occurances of "TT" that are full words, and not partial words. `TT` would be found, where as `TTBM` would not.

Comment: Ah, surround it with word breaks, `\b`.  Like: "/\\b".$word.'\\b(?!.*<\/a>)/'

Answer (score 1):

## Description

This will look for all words with prefex 'cat' outside an anchor tag

You'll need to use a case insensitive option on the regex search command.

`(?<=^|<[\/]a>)[^<]*\b(cat\w*|[^<]*?\s\bcat\w*)\b`

[image]

## PHP example of the regex

```
 <?php
$sourcestring="CatSoup<a href='...'>catsup</a>catfish tag itself like <a href='/part/catsup'> ... </a>";
preg_match_all('/(?<=^|<[\/]a>)[^<]*\b(cat\w*|[^<]*?\s\bcat\w*)\b/i',$sourcestring,$matches);
echo "<pre>".print_r($matches,true);
?>

$matches Array:
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => CatSoup
            [1] => catfish
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => CatSoup
            [1] => catfish
        )

)
```

To capture the location within the string you'd use the flag PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE, but I'm not sure how to pull that value from the array.
`preg_match_all('/<a\b[^>]*>(cat\w*|[^<]*?\s\bcat\w*)/i',$sourcestring,$matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);`

## Disclaimer

The inner text should really be pulled out using an html parsing engine first, this will avoid problematic edge cases where a regex parsing HTML text will fail. However I see in comments on the OP that you're in control of the HTML and it's rather basic so this disclaimer may not really apply.

Comment: This is really great, but If I'm understanding correctly, this is return instances that ARE linked - or ARE within the <a> tag.. am I wrong? I hope not because I am not getting any results. `Pattern = /<a\b[^>]*>(TTM\w*|[^<]*?\s\bTTM\w*) ... none`

Comment: My Intention is to find the UNLINKED items.

Comment: Oh ok... I misunderstood that bit... lets see

Comment: PS - what did you use to generate that nifty flowchart?

Comment: I'm using http://www.debuggex.com/ . Although it doesn't support lookbehinds like the one I just updated the answer for here. It's still handy for understanding the expression flow.  There is also http://www.regexper.com/. They do a pretty good job too, but it's not real time as you're typing.